# Texlipseで画像を貼る方法

Tags: eclipse, latex

こんにちは。
LaTeXをTexlipseで使っています。そこで質問なのですが、エクスプローラに保存した写真を貼ってpdf上に出力するためにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: latexに画像を挿入する方法（文法）が判らないという事ですか？

Comment: そうですね。具体的には構文はわかりますが、latexはどこにセーブしてあるファイルを読み込むことができるのか・ファイル名と対応しているファイルの種類などを教えていただきたいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[medemanabu.net/latex/graphicx-figure-includegraphics](http://medemanabu.net/latex/graphicx-figure-includegraphics) とか、[yamamo10.jp/~yamamoto/comp/latex/make_doc/insert_fig/index.php](http://yamamo10.jp/%7Eyamamoto/comp/latex/make_doc/insert_fig/index.php) とか、の記事を参考にしてください。

"Latex 画像","Latex 写真"といった検索語をつかってGoogleなどで検索すると容易に関連する情報が見つかると思います。